# query of showing same data (or value) twice with different months in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

Suppose I have a user table that records user id and I have a Bill_record table that records bills of months of user. let assume XYZ did not pay bills of Jan and Feb. Now at March I want to see the list of due users of previous months. if run

`select c.User_ID from user as c where c.User_ID not in "
                + "(select b.User_ID from Bill_record as b where "
                + "b.User_ID = c.User_ID and "
                + "(b.Date between 2015-1-1 and 2015-2-28"
                + "))`

it only show XYZ once but I want to see it twice along with month name. What will be the query in that case?

Update1: here I attach my table structure.
[image: this is client table. primary key is User_ID]
[image: this is Bill_Record table. PK is SL (serial no. auto incremented)]

now you can see from bill_record table that user 10001,10002 did not pay bill of March, April and May. I want to have a list that contain both 1001 and 10002 three times along with month mane.

Comment: could you upload your table structure?

Comment: @Blip I've attached structure of both table. first one is User table and second one is bill_record table

Answer (score 1):

You should break up your query to check by each month. The way your query is currently written, you're only looking for users who haven't paid any bills between Jan first and Feb 28th.

To get all users who didn't pay a bill in January:

```
SELECT 'January', u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN(
  SELECT user_id
  FROM bills
  WHERE MONTH(payment) = 1);
```

Likewise, you can do the same for February. To combine them, you could use a UNION:

```
SELECT 'January', u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN(
  SELECT user_id
  FROM bills
  WHERE MONTH(payment) = 1)
UNION
SELECT 'February', u.id
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN(
  SELECT user_id
  FROM bills
  WHERE MONTH(payment) = 2);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fa9d/2) example.

Comment: I got your answer but I want it dynamically. Like, if user set a date in between my program will show the list of due users of month accordingly.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it using mysql query or else I might write a piece of java code to loop through the months and prepare queries inside the loop according the month name then joining it together I can finally have the complete query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do a query on a date range.

```
SELECT *
FROM order_details
WHERE order_date >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE)
AND order_date <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Or your program could do it dynamically itself - as in run a little conversion to only show the month of the date it receives.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(br.Date) AS Month, u.Name, u.User_ID, br.Bill_Tk FROM
Bill_record br
LEFT JOIN
user u on u.User_ID = br.User_ID
ORDER BY u.User_ID, MONTH(br.Date)
```

see is on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cd71/4/0)

Comment: it shows the given bill_record of users but i want the due users record. According to your database I want to see this output -
monthh   name    id           bill
January  Farin   10001     800
Feb        Farin    10001    800
Jan         Farhan 10002    1000
Feb        Farhan  10002    1000
Jan         Sazzad   1122      800
Feb        sazzad    1122      800
Mar        sazzad     1122     800
Apr        sazzad      1122    800
May       sazzad       1122   800

Comment: Sorry in the previous comment i messed up. please see this comment:
it shows the given bill_record of users but i want the due users record. According to your database I want to see this output -
(monthh   name    id           bill)->
 {(January  Farin   10001     800),
 (Feb      Farin    10001    800)};
  {(Jan     Farhan 10002    1000),
 (Feb      Farhan  10002    1000)};
 {(Jan     Sazzad  1122      800),
 (Feb     sazzad   1122      800),
 (Mar     sazzad   1122     800)
 (Apr      sazzad   1122    800)
 (May     sazzad   1122   800)}

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon how do you calculate whether a bill is due or not?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon I have edited the query to include just what you wanted.

Comment: The query I've written on my question that returns the due users of a single month but if a user have due for sever months that didn't show a user multiple times and that is my problem.
Sorry, what you have edited , I didn't get it! the output remains same except the order ! Farin must show two times , farhan must show two times and sazzad must show five times!